# How to find open and closing braces present in a string (a list converted into string)?

Tags: robotframework

My requirement is to check whether the input is list or not using robot framework.

I tried using type(${temp}).**name** with evaluate function, which works in case of list and fails for string type.

Below is the error message -

Evaluating expression 'type(testdata).**name**' failed: SyntaxError: invalid token (, line 1)

Tried to use regex, but no luck.:(

Code :-
 testRegEx
    ${match}    Run Keyword    Should Match Regexp    ["swerwv","sfsdfdsf","edsfdf"]    \[\s\S\]
    Log To Console    ${match}

output:- 
FAIL : '["swerwv","sfsdfdsf","edsfdf"]' does not match '[\s\S]'

I'm new to robotframework. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might want to consider changing the title of your question. If your true goal is to test whether or not a variable is a list, that's what your title should say.

Answer (score 1):

> My requirement is to check whether the input is list or not using robot framework.

You can use robot's special syntax for `evaluate` and the various keywords which accept expressions, where you omit the brackets in the variable reference to pass the actual variable to the expression (versus passing the value of the variable).

Example:

```
*** Variables ***
@{a_list}      one  two  three

*** Test Cases ***
Test that variable is a list
    run keyword unless  type(a_list) == list
    ...   Fail   not a list
```

This feature is mentioned in the [Evaluating expressions](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluating%20expressions) section of the built-in library.